# assigning and moving instances in a array

Tags: c#, arrays

```
 void InsertScoreAndLeaderBoard(int pointageCurrent, string nameCurrent)
{
  int savePosition;
  string saveName;
  if (IsBetterScore(pointageCurrent))
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < leaderBoardNum.Length; i++)
    {
      if (pointageCurrent > leaderBoardNum[i])
      {
        savePosition = leaderBoardNum[i] ;
        saveName = leaderBoardName[i];
        leaderBoardNum[i] = pointageCurrent;
        leaderBoardName[i] = nameCurrent;
        for (int j = leaderBoardNum.Length; j > 0; j--)
        {

        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

so i am kinda stuck in this code i am trying to write. I have to put a username and his score to this leader board. The thing is that i never modified an array in a way so, for example, if i replace the 2nd place with the current numbers and name, the ancient score and name is transferred to 3rd place and the old score of the 3rd place moves to 4th place and so on. The only data that has to be destroyed while moving the arrays is the last place (or position 0).

Comment: Consider using a `List<T>` instead. You can easily insert (`Insert()`) and remove items (`RemoveAt()`). Alternatively, you can maintain a master list of all scores, then use a LINQ query to sort and get the top ten. Additionally, consider creating your own class that houses both the `Name` and `Score` rather than maintaining two separate lists (of `string` and `int`). For example, `class HighScore { public string Name; public int Score; }`

Comment: IMO you're using the wrong data structure for what you're trying to do. Using a List would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments, using arrays for this purpose is probably not a correct choice. It will make your code unreadable/complex.

There may be a valid case of using an array for this purpose: when you are trying to be very memory efficient and performance is crucial.
Suggested solutions (Lists, LINQ) allow clean (easy to read and maintain) code, but add some overhead.

Here's a sample console app, which shows how it could be done with an array, to be memory efficient (first) and also fast (second):

```cs
using System;

namespace ScoreBoardApp
{
    // How a single scoreboard entry looks like.
    struct ScoreboardEntry
    {
        public ushort scoredPoints;
        public string playerName;

        public ScoreboardEntry( ushort points, string name )
        {
            scoredPoints = points;
            playerName = name;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        // This is our scoreboard array. Most games start with fake entries,
        // to set some expectations, so are we. (Make sure you order them
        // correctly here and the data is clean and neat.)
        // To start empty use:
        // scoreboard = new ScoreboardEntry[10];
        private readonly ScoreboardEntry[] scoreboard = new [] {
            new ScoreboardEntry( 7777, "Winner" ),
            new ScoreboardEntry( 6666, "Hans" ),
            new ScoreboardEntry( 5555, "Anna" ),
            new ScoreboardEntry( 4444, "Sven" ),
            new ScoreboardEntry( 3333, "Elsa" ),
            new ScoreboardEntry( 2222, "Kurt" ),
            new ScoreboardEntry( 1111, "Ollie" ),
            new ScoreboardEntry(  999, "Bertha" ),
            new ScoreboardEntry(  888, "Joana" ),
            new ScoreboardEntry(  777, "Javaid" )
        };

        // What to show, when no player name given.
        private const string playerNamePlaceholder = "<none>";

        // In case we need to start from scratch.
        public void ClearBoard()
        {
            // We could just do (after we strip "readonly" from our field):
            //     scoreboard = new ScoreboardEntry[scoreboard.Length];
            // But this way we're re-using memory, and are still relatvely
            // fast:
            for (var i = 0; i < scoreboard.Length; i++)
                scoreboard[i] = new ScoreboardEntry();
        }

        // This shows current state of the scoreboard (not very fast
        // nor efficient).
        public void PrintScoreboard()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---+-----------------+-------");
            Console.WriteLine("{0,2} | {1,-15} | {2,6}", "#", "Name", "Score");
            Console.WriteLine("---+-----------------+-------");
            var len = scoreboard.Length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "{0,2:N0} | {1,-15} | {2,6:N0}",
                    i + 1,
                    scoreboard[i].playerName ?? playerNamePlaceholder,
                    scoreboard[i].scoredPoints
                );
            Console.WriteLine("---+-----------------+-------");
        }

        // This checks if the player's score reached the scoreboard
        // tells us so, and if yes, then places his entry on the board.
        // Should be quite efficient & fast (apart from console output).
        public void RecordScore(ushort playerScore, string playerName)
        {
            // Cleaning the input data.
            if (playerName != null)
            {
                // TODO: Deal with pesky control characters inside!
                playerName = playerName.TrimStart();
                playerName = playerName.Substring(0, Math.Min(15, playerName.Length)).TrimEnd();
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(playerName))
                playerName = null;

            // Let's compare to the last scoreboard entry.
            var place = scoreboard.Length - 1;
            if (playerScore <= scoreboard[place].scoredPoints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "{0} did not make it with score {1:N0}",
                    playerName ?? playerNamePlaceholder,
                    playerScore
                );
                return;
            }

            // We'll go from bottom, to the top, to find correct landing
            // spot, and at the same time, move the beaten entries down.
            while (place > 0 && playerScore > scoreboard[place - 1].scoredPoints)
            {
                place--;
                scoreboard[place + 1] = scoreboard[place];
            }
            // Let's record our winner.
            scoreboard[place].scoredPoints = playerScore;
            scoreboard[place].playerName = playerName;
            Console.WriteLine(
                "{0} is #{1:N0} with score {2:N0}",
                playerName ?? playerNamePlaceholder,
                place + 1,
                playerScore
            );
        }

        // Let's play.
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Program();
            // Initial state.
            p.PrintScoreboard();
            // This player should not reach the board.
            p.RecordScore(666, null);
            p.PrintScoreboard();
            // This one scored same as the #10, which is not enough.
            p.RecordScore(777, "Almost there");
            p.PrintScoreboard();
            // This one should land as #5.
            p.RecordScore(4000, " Fifth ");
            p.PrintScoreboard();
            // This is the #1.
            p.RecordScore(ushort.MaxValue, "Best !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            p.PrintScoreboard();

            // No app is considered worthy, without accepting some user
            // input. This one uses execution parameters.
            if (args.Length >= 1 && args.Length <= 2)
            {
                ushort score = 0;
                string name = null;
                if (ushort.TryParse(args[0], out score))
                {
                    if (args.Length > 1)
                        name = args[1];
                    p.RecordScore(score, name);
                    p.PrintScoreboard();
                }
                else
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Give <score> and <name> as parameters.");
            }

            // Let's sweep everything before we go to sleep.
            p.ClearBoard();
            p.PrintScoreboard();
        }
    }
}
```

To make it faster, but a bit less efficient, we could use a class instead of a struct (and adjust code accordingly).